# Use non-root user configuration for root account

Tags: command-line, sudo, configuration, su

When I work with the terminal and use `su` or `sudo` to execute a command with the root user's permissions, is it possible to apply the configuration of my "non-root user" (from which I am invoking `su` or `sudo`) stored in this user's home directory?

For instance, consider that (being logged on as a non-root user) I would like to edit the configuration file `/etc/some_file` using `vim` and that my vim configuration file is located at `/home/myuser/.vimrc`. Firing up the command line and typing `sudo vim /etc/some_file`, I would want "my" beautiful and well-configured `vim` to show up. But what I get is an ugly `vim` with the default configuration, no plugins etc.

Can I make `su` or `sudo` use my user's configuration files instead of the root user's files located at /root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sudo -E`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html) to preserve your environment:

```
$ export FOO=1
$ sudo -E env | grep FOO
FOO=1
```

That will preserve `$HOME` and any other environment variables you had, so the same configuration files you started with will be accessed by the programs running as root.

You can update `sudoers` to disable the [`env_reset`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html) setting, which clears out all environment variables and is generally enabled by default. You may have to enable the ability to use `sudo -E` at all in there as well. There are a few other `sudoers` settings that might be relevant: `env_keep`, which lets you specify specific variables to keep by default, and `env_remove`, which declares variables to delete always. You can use `sudo sudo -V` to see which variables are/are not preserved.

An alternative, if you can't modify `sudoers`, is to provide your environment explicitly:

```
sudo env HOME=$HOME command here
```

You can make a shell alias to do that automatically so you don't have to type it in.

Note that doing this (either way) can have potentially unwanted side effects: if the program you run tries to make files in your home directory, for example, those files will be created as root and your ordinary user won't be able to write to them.

For the specific case of `vim`, you could also put your `.vimrc` as the system-wide `/etc/vimrc` if you're the only user of this system.

Comment: Thanks, all approaches work. Eventually I went with `Defaults env_reset` and `env_keep += "HOME"`, thus preserving my `$HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Set up sudo to preserve the `HOME` environment variable.

Run `visudo` to edit the sudo configuration. Make sure that the option `always_set_home` is not set, and that `HOME` is present in the `env_keep` list. Add the following lines:

```
Defaults !always_set_home
Defaults env_keep+="HOME"
```

Remove a line like `Defaults always_set_home` if there is one.

Comment: Although according to the `sudo` manpages this should work, I couldn't make it work, even after disabling `env_reset` (which is a necessary step according to the manual).

Comment: @SirSureE.Nuff Does it work if you add `Defaults env_keep+="HOME"`? Sorry, I forgot about this one initially.

Comment: No problem! Yes, adding `env_keep (...)` solved my problem. See my comment to the answer by Mr. Homer.