# gksudo not honoring configuration in /etc/sudoers

Tags: sudo, gksu

Some time ago I posted a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145038) which was related to whether it is possible to preserve environment variables when `sudo`ing to a different user. As it turned out, this is indeed possible.

When invoking `gksudo` today to execute a GUI application as the root user, I was expecting that the preservation of environment variables (in my case `$HOME`) would also work for `gksudo` as it is configured via the same file, namely `/etc/sudoers`. As it turned out, this does not seem to be the case.

For example, executing `sudo vim` will start up an instance of `vim`, correctly getting the configuration from the invoking user's home folder because I configured `sudo` to preserve `$HOME`. But `gksudo gvim` will fire up a "vanilla" `gvim` instance.

Is it necessary to separately configure `gksudo` to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think I'm having a similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378732/etc-sudoers-rule-not-being-obeyed