# Is there a graphical sudo (kdesudo, gksudo, su-to-root, ...) tool that works passwordless?

Tags: sudo, root, gui, su, gksu

Apparently [gksudo is not obeying `/etc/sudoers`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168283/gksudo-not-honoring-configuration-in-etc-sudoers), neither [does `kdesu`](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20914).

Therefore asking the other way around...

Is there any `su-to-root`, `gksudo`, `kdesudo`, etc. alike tool, that supports starting gui applications as root or different user with an option to skip entering a password?

Comment: You should be able to do it with `pkexec` if `polkit` is installed on your system.

Answer (score 5):

The point of a “graphical sudo” is to prompt for the user's password. If you don't want a password prompt, use plain `sudo`.

Run `visudo` to create an entry in the `sudoers` file with the `NOPASSWD` tag. Note that [this entry must come after any `ALL` entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).

Make sure that the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables are preserved, to allow running X11 applications.

```
adrelanos ALL = (ALL) ALL
adrelanos ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: my-x11-application-to-run-as-root
Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY HOME XAUTHORITY"
```

Comment: `$XAUTHORITY` is empty on my system (openSUSE 13.2, `konsole`).

Comment: @HaukeLaging If `XAUTHORITY` is not set, `~/.Xauthority` is used. Good point though: `HOME` needs to be preserved in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH with X forwarding (`-X`) and a key without password.

SSH has the useful feature that keys can be limited to one command. This could be a kind of `sudo` replacement: Prevent the user from doing as `root` what he wants; limit him to what he must be capable of doing.

Comment: Sounds like overkill for a local system. Nothing simpler?